# how to categorize values based on condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to categorize my temperature data as:

**very low**: <=15 Celsius

**Low:**:>=15 and < 25 Celsius

**normal**:>=25 and < 35 Celsius

**high**:>=35 and < 45 Celsius

**very high**:>= 45 Celsius

temp  category

32
33
34
35
36
30
31

I have done something like this:

```
=IF(AND(a1<15,OR(a1>=15  a1<=25),OR (a1>25 a1<=35) ,OR(a1>35  a1<=45) ,OR(a1>45)),"Verylow","low","medium","high","veryhigh")
```

but it is not working. I want to fill values in category field. please help!!

Comment: filling data manually is not an option as the no. of columns are in 1000's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved.
correct formula will be

```
=IF( A2<15, "verylow", IF( A2<25, "low",IF(A2<35,"medium",IF(A2<45,"high","veryhigh" ))))
```